# Spark connection to network folder

Tags: excel, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I need to save the content of an Excel file into a Hive table using Spark, and the Excel file is saved in a network folder (I can't save this file in a database). I found the code to create the table, but I don't know how to connect Spark to the network folder to read the file. Do you know any way to do this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: use https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel Spark plugin to read excel. If excel file isn't huge, just copy it to a driver, and load it from a local file.

Comment: Thank you @addmeaning for your support! Can you be a little more specific? When you say that I can load it from a local file, you mean load it in Cloudera, right? And is it possible to automatically update the file in Cloudera every time it is modified in the driver or automatically update it each month? Thank you!